# Add css loader to next.config.js

Tags: webpack, next.js, webpack-style-loader

Currently I have this `next.config.js`:

```js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less')
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  require.extensions['.less'] = () => {}
}

module.exports = withCSS(
  withLess(
    withSass({
      lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    })
  )
)
```

I'm trying to use `react-rce` but in [the docs](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte#required-webpack-configuration) they say that I need to add a `style-loader` to my webpack config.

E.g

```js
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
```

but I don't understand how to add it into my current file. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add additional module rules for css-loader in your file like this:

```js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less')
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  require.extensions['.less'] = () => {}
}

module.exports = withCSS(
  withLess(
    withSass({
      lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
      webpack: config => {
        config.module.rules.push(
          {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          }
        );
        return config;
      }
    })
  )
)
```

Comment: thanks! I had to add a `return config` to the bottom

Comment: oo ya, i forgot to mention that, will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install css-loader, npm i css-loader.
If you use NextJs. touch the next.config.js file and
add the following code, save, and restart the server.

```
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
```